# "Bottles of Beer" Recursion Java

Tags: java, recursion

So I just recently got to the topic of recursion, which was making sense mathematically. This task required me to recursively print out the "99 Bottles of Beer on the Wall" song. This is what I have so far

```
public static int bottlesOfBeer(int n) {
    if (n > 1) {
        System.out.println(n + "bottles of beer on the wall, " + n + " bottles of beer.");
        System.out.println("You take one down, pass it around. " + (n-1) + "bottles of beer on the wall.");
        bottlesOfBeer(n-1);
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

The error is that the program doesn't seem to recognize the recursive substructure going on. I'd like to know why it isn't recognizing it. I should also note that this is homework, so just a nudge in the right direction is all I ask.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't recognize the recursive substructure"?  What is the output of this code?  When you step through in a debugger, where does the behavior differ from what you expect?

Comment: your method's signature indicates that it returns an int. but you never return an int in your method.

Comment: You should probably `return 0;` or change the return type to `void`

Comment: You need to change `bottlesOfBeer(n-1);` to `return bottlesOfBeer(n-1);` and change `return;` to `return 0;`

Comment: You're not using the return value. Just change the return type to `void`.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the help everyone. Dumb mistake by me :(

Answer (score 0):

The error you're *probably* receiving has nothing to do with the program not "recognizing the recursive substructure". I'm willing to bet it's because your method declaration is returning an `int` but your terminating condition caught in your `else` is returning nothing. Re-declare your `bottlesOfBeer(int n)` method to be `public static void bottlesOfBeer(int n)`.

Comment: Got it. This would be much better then:

Answer (score 0):

Like other people have said in the comments, the problem most likely has to do with the fact that it is a method that returns an integer, as shown in your code,

```
    public static int bottlesOfBeer(int n)
```

If I might suggest a change,

```
    public static void bottlesOfBeer(int n)
```

Or perhaps merely allow the method to return a number.